# Good places to submit a business profile?

Tags: seo, backlinks

We have a new graphic/web design site that we've created and we'd like to give it a boost in terms of back links.

What are the obvious places to submit a website to achieve some good back links? And what would be the recurring work load (if any) that those back links would need? Are there any good industry specific websites we could submit a profile to?

E.g Twitter, would need constant interaction and new content with back links to the website.

**UPDATE:**
I've always felt it's worth it but after several years trying to submit different websites, I've never successfully managed to get a site into DMOZ!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider:

- The [Alltop](http://alltop.com) blog directory. (Requires you keep a blog updated, and that your content is useful.)
- The ever-growing list of [CSS directories and site design showcases](http://www.cssish.com/).
- The [Krop](http://www.krop.com/) creative database. (Create a profile and include a link back to your main site in your company/personal resume.)
- The [Sortfolio](http://sortfolio.com/) directory of web designers.
- Submitting posts to respected web-related blogs with open calls for writers, such as [Think Vitamin,](http://thinkvitamin.com/write-for-us/) [A List Apart,](http://www.alistapart.com/contribute/) and [Smashing Magazine.](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/how-to-become-a-smashing-magazine-author/)

Comment: Cheers Nick, always love your answers!! Are there any obvious places to submit, maybe more general?

Comment: @Rob You're welcome. I'm afraid I don't know of any general website directories that are worth being listed in (except Google!). DMOZ is perhaps the only one worth applying to, but you need to be well-established to get into it. They rarely list new sites, from my experience.